# Can't log in -- Gitorious server setup on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, git

I just finished going through [this guide](http://www.ookami.cz/projekty/gitorious.php) to create a Gitorious server on Ubuntu Server 9.10. With a few difficulties, I managed to get through it all, and I can see the default FAQ, contact information, etc. I can also register accounts fine.

When I log in, though, I am redirected to the dashboard. This would be normal behavior, except I'm not logged in when I get there. I can't find any cookies or session variables. Oddly, this only happens when I enter *correct* login information--when I enter an incorrect login, it stays at the login screen.

I am using a self-signed ssl certificate.

I'll add information at request, but as there are no errors I don't have any solid data on hand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your gitorious.yml file with the correct hostname for cookies to work (such as session cookie). For more information, see here: https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/ErrorMessages#Invalid+subdomain+name++subdomain%3E.+Session+cookies+will+not+work!

After you change the hostname, you also need to clear cookies from your browser.